# Google Places not loading into TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I have a UIViewController which presents another UIViewController as a UISearchResultsController.

I would like this searchResultsController to display GooglePlaces upon search.

I am getting all the autocomplete predictions printed out in the console, however, the UITableView is not loading the data.

Here is my function;

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        if searchController.isActive {
            searchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden = false
        }
        if searchController.searchBar.text == "" {
            self.searchResults.removeAll()
        } else {
            guard let query = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
            GMSPlacesClient.shared().autocompleteQuery(query, bounds: nil, filter: filteredResults) { (predictions, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error as Any)
                    return
                } else {
                    guard let searchPredictions = predictions else { return }
                    self.searchResults = searchPredictions
                    print("PREDICTION: \(searchPredictions)")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.resultsTableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

### Sanitation Checks

1. TableView Delegate
2. TableView DataSource
3. Predictions
4. numberOfRowsInSection

1 & 2 are set to self.

3 is printing;

```
GMSAutocompletePrediction 0x6000037f0450: "England Street, Charlotte, NC, USA", id: EiJFbmdsYW5kIFN0cmVldCwgQ2hhcmxvdHRlLCBOQywgVVNB, types: (
    route,
    geocode
```

4 is giving me the correct amount of predictions

I am following the custom implementation from google here;

https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically

Under 'Get place predictions programmatically'

As always any help appreciated.

### Update: TableView Methods

```
extension SearchResultsController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return searchResults.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let resultsCell = resultsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: resultsCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ResultsCell
    let resultsAttributedFullText = searchResults[indexPath.row].attributedFullText.string
    resultsCell.textLabel?.text = resultsAttributedFullText
    return resultsCell
}
```

### UPDATE: cellForRowAt

Upon further inspection of my cellForRowAt function;

```
let results = searchResults[indexPath.row].placeID
```

printing `results` to the console doesn't give me any output.

### UPDATE:

Adding breakpoint result at `self.searchResults = searchPredictions`

[image: breakpoint print out]

### UPDATE:

In the console I'm getting the following error;

```
[BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1300) [C3.1:2][0x7ffd627057e0] get output frames failed, state 8196
```

Not sure if this could be connected to my issue or not but noting it anyway.

Comment: is `self` and instance of `UISearchController ` or `UISearchResultsController ` ?

Comment: self is the searchResultsController of the UISearchController, where I state DataSource & Delegate set to self I mean this is for the UITableView.  Ill update for clarity.

Comment: try logging `self.searchResults`. Your reference here seems to the culprit.

Comment: my self.searchResults is HERE IS SEARCH RESULTS: [GMSAutocompletePrediction 0x6000015c1290: "England's Lane, London, UK", id: EhpFbmdsYW5kJ3MgTGFuZSwgTG9uZG9uLCBVSw, types: (
    route,
    geocode

Comment: @V_rohit I've updated my question to show the result on breakpoint.  self.searchResults does seem to be the issue it isn't empty but numberOrItemsInSection isn't ever updated?

Comment: Please...upload the tableview methods of your code

Comment: @V_rohit I have updated the question to include all the tableview methods

Comment: put all your else code in your `DispatchQueue` and try again...if this project is not confidential would you upload it on GitHub or send it to me?

Comment: @V_rohit let me know how you want it sent

Comment: Got your project

Answer (score 0):

Could you replace the following:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
     self.resultsTableView.reloadData()
}
```

to

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
     searchController.searchResultsController.resultsTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: This gives me; Value of type 'UIViewController?' has no member 'resultsTableView'

Comment: In which class is the `updateSearchResults ` method implemented?

Comment: Its in class SearchResultsController: UIViewController, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating

Comment: From the code you posted and your explanation, I assume you want to display the data in another view controller (`UISearchResultsController `) and not in the current `UISearchController ` from which you did the search. Right?

Comment: Correct.  I am displaying it inside uisearchResultsController

Comment: After `self.searchResults = searchPredictions` I assume `self.searchResults` is not empty. Also, how do you format your data? Can you show the `cellForRow` method code?